# What are tdf files used for in embedded system (c code)?

Tags: c, embedded

I have seen the use of tdf files in embedded software written in c, and i dont understand what they are used for?

```
#define OSAL_ADD_TABLE_FILE_DEF( file )
OSAL_ADD_TABLE_FILE_DEF( MDL\COMM\pstn.tdf )
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the context and the snippet of code provided, I would say the embedded system is using a .tdf "Table Definition File" to describe some data it needs to access.. possibly from some database.

http://www.jafsoft.com/doco/asctortf_using_table_definition_files.html